# How to update models / vectors on runtime, on daily basis?

Tags: python, design-patterns, scikit-learn, pytorch, data-science

I have a simple `web app` which uses sklearn transformed vectors (tfidf / count / normalizer) & other pytorch (transformer models). I usually dump these models via `joblib`. This app calls these models via fastapi based apis. Until now everything is fine.

- But the above listed vectors and models are updated on daily basis, on runtime. By the part of same application which uses it. So, whenever new files are ready we starts using them.
- Whenever we get a call from api, we search for todays model and does:
  `joblib.load` then respond to api calls. In this process, whenever we are getting too many calls, we are doing many times `joblib.load` and finally we starts getting `Too many files open OSError.`
- If we wouldn't be updating these models daily then I could have done loading once in global variables. But now I don't have a clear and best idea, to design it in such a way that, we can update models on daily basis & whenever the models are available for today, then start using them.
- Also, one more constraint, until the models for today are not available, we use yesterdays model to serve requests.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is load the model once, use the model in memory, and then every so often check whether a new model is available on disk and reload it if an updated version is available.

Comment: yes thats what i want to do. Thanks for clarification.